# Do I need to use mysql_close(connection)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code in db.php to connect to my DB.

```
<?php
$DB_HOST        = "localhost";
$DB_NAME        = "db";
$DB_USER        = "user";
$DB_PASSWORD        = "pass";

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($DB_NAME , $con);
?>
```

In my other script I include it using:

```
include("db.php");
```

In some cases I receive the ff error:

[10-Mar-2012 10:47:20] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: User db_user already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in /home/user/public_html/sc/db.php on line 8

Now, I am wondering if I need to close the connection like:

```
<?php
include("db.php");

//other stuff here

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

BTW, I have a value of 100 max_connections in my MySQL config.

I also research about persistent connection and I believe my code above is not a persistent connection.

Comment: Always free up resources you don't need anymore.

Comment: O_O ------------------------>

Comment: Look at the right side of the screen. there are dozen questions listed on the exactly the same topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this won't help you if you close it at the end of the script. `mysql_close()` is just useful in case you want to free up resources before you end your script, because your connection is closed as soon as execution of the script ends

Answer (score -1):

If you don't close your connections, they will stay open and take up precious resources on the server. I guess there's there the security point too, you don't want to risk someone getting a hold of the connection.
I prefer to put my database in a class and use __construct to create the connection, and __destruct to close the connection. If your unfamiliar with classes. The __construct and __destruct gets called automatically when you create and destroy a class.

Edit:
There was originally meant to be an example. But I have a basic but working mysql class here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651249/1246494.

It shows the usage of mysql_close and how I was trying to relate it to the class destructor. The point was, any network connection should be closed, whether your database is on a remote server, or localhost.