# OOP database connect/disconnect class

Tags: php, oop, class

I have just started learning the concept of Object oriented programming and have put together a class for connecting to a database, selecting database and closing the database connection. So far everything seems to work out okay except closing the connection to the database.

```
    class Database {

    private $host, $username, $password;
    public function __construct($ihost, $iusername, $ipassword){
        $this->host = $ihost;
        $this->username = $iusername;
        $this->password = $ipassword;
    }
    public function connectdb(){
        mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password)
            OR die("There was a problem connecting to the database.");
        echo 'successfully connected to database<br />';
    }
    public function select($database){
        mysql_select_db($database)
            OR die("There was a problem selecting the database.");
        echo 'successfully selected database<br />';
    }
    public function disconnectdb(){
        mysql_close($this->connectdb())
            OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");
    }
}

$database = new database('localhost', 'root', 'usbw');
$database->connectdb();
$database->select('msm');
$database->disconnectdb();
```

When I attempt to disconnect from the database I get the following error message:

```
Warning: mysql_close(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in F:\Programs\webserver\root\oop\oop.php on line 53
```

I'm guessing it isn't as simple as placing the connectdb method within the parenthesis of the mysql_close function but can't find the right way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would add a connection/link variable to your class, and use a destructor.
That will also save you from haveing to remember to close your connection, cause it's done automatically.
It is the $this->link that you need to pass to your mysql_close().

```
class Database {

    private $link;
    private $host, $username, $password, $database;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database){
        $this->host        = $host;
        $this->username    = $username;
        $this->password    = $password;
        $this->database    = $database;

        $this->link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password)
            OR die("There was a problem connecting to the database.");

        mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->link)
            OR die("There was a problem selecting the database.");

        return true;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        return $result;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        mysql_close($this->link)
            OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");
    }

}
```

Example Usage:

```
<?php
    $db = new Database("localhost", "username", "password", "testDatabase");

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM students");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "First Name: " . $row['firstname'] ."<br />";
        echo "Last Name: "  . $row['lastname']  ."<br />";
        echo "Address: "    . $row['address']   ."<br />";
        echo "Age: "        . $row['age']       ."<br />";
        echo "<hr />";
    }
?>
```

Edit:
So people can actually use the class, I added the missing properties/methods.
The next step would be to expand on the query method, to include protection against injection, and any other helper functions.
 
I made the following changes:

- Added the missing private properties
- Added `__construct($host, $username, $password, $database)`
- Merged `connectdb()` and `select()` into `__construct()` saving an extra two lines of code.
- Added `query($query)`
- Example Usage

Please if I made a typo or mistake, leave a constructive comment, so I can fix it for others.

**edit 23/06/2018**

As pointed out mysql is quite outdated and as this question still receives regular visits I thought I'd post an updated solution.

```
class Database {

    private $mysqli;
    private $host, $username, $password, $database;

    /**
     * Creates the mysql connection.
     * Kills the script on connection or database errors.
     * 
     * @param string $host
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @param string $database
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database){
        $this->host        = $host;
        $this->username    = $username;
        $this->password    = $password;
        $this->database    = $database;

        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password)
            OR die("There was a problem connecting to the database.");

        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        $this->mysqli->select_db($this->database);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the currently selected database.
     */
    public function print_database_name()
    {
        /* return name of current default database */
        if ($result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
            $row = $result->fetch_row();
            printf("Selected database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
            $result->close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * On error returns an array with the error code.
     * On success returns an array with multiple mysql data.
     * 
     * @param string $query
     * @return array
     */
    public function query($query) {
        /* array returned, includes a success boolean */
        $return = array();

        if(!$result = $this->mysqli->query($query))
        {
            $return['success'] = false;
            $return['error'] = $this->mysqli->error;

            return $return;
        }

        $return['success'] = true;
        $return['affected_rows'] = $this->mysqli->affected_rows;
        $return['insert_id'] = $this->mysqli->insert_id;

        if(0 == $this->mysqli->insert_id)
        {
            $return['count'] = $result->num_rows;
            $return['rows'] = array();
            /* fetch associative array */
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $return['rows'][] = $row;
            }

            /* free result set */
            $result->close();
        }

        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * Automatically closes the mysql connection
     * at the end of the program.
     */
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->mysqli->close()
            OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
<?php
    $db = new Database("localhost", "username", "password", "testDatabase");

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM students");

    if(true == $result['success'])
    {
        echo "Number of rows: " . $result['count'] ."<br />";
        foreach($result['rows'] as $row)
        {
            echo "First Name: " . $row['firstname'] ."<br />";
            echo "Last Name: "  . $row['lastname']  ."<br />";
            echo "Address: "    . $row['address']   ."<br />";
            echo "Age: "        . $row['age']       ."<br />";
            echo "<hr />";
        }
    }

    if(false == $result['success'])
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: " . $result['error'] ."<br />";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you're not returning anything from `connectdb()` yet you're passing this function's return to `mysql_close()`.

Comment: BTW if you're going to do it like this, you might as well keep a real resource for the database connection inside your class.

Comment: What do you mean when you say keep a real source for the database connection inside the class?

Comment: @crm: Add a private member and store it in there, like `$this->connection`.

Comment: mysql_connect() returns a "resource" variable that represents the connection. then you can pass it to mysql_query and mysql_close, so that you can work with several conncetions at once - one per instance of your class. The way you wrote it, your class only encapsulates the calls, and the instance is meaningless.

Comment: @Dvir Thanks that explains it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware that `mysql_*` functions were introduced in PHP 4, which is more then 1 yours ago. This API is extremely old, and the process has begun to actually [deprecating this extension](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799).

You should not in 2012 write new code with `mysql_*` functions.

There exist two very good alternative : [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).  Both of which are already written with object oriented code in mind, and they also give you ability to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

That example you showed in the original post written with PDO would look like this:

```
//connect to the the database
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=msm', 'username', 'password');
//disconnects
$connection = null;
```

Of course there are more complicated use-case, but the point stand - time to evolve.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_close requires a parameter to disconnect but you are providing nothing.

```
class Database {

    private $host, $username, $password, $con;

    public function __construct($ihost, $iusername, $ipassword){
        $this->host = $ihost;
        $this->username = $iusername;
        $this->password = $ipassword;
        $this->con = false;
    }


    public function connect() {
        $connect = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
        return $connect;
    }


    public function connectdb(){
        $conn = $this->connect();
        if($conn)
        {
            $this->con = true;
            echo "Successsfully Connected. 
";
            return true;
        }
        else {
            echo "Sorry Could Not Connect. 
";
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function select($database){
        if($this->con)
        {
            if(mysql_select_db($database))
            {
                echo "Successfully Connected Database. $database. 
";
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Unknown database. 
";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "No active Connection. 
";
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function disconnectdb(){
        if($this->con)
        {
            if(mysql_close($this->connect()))
            {
                $this->con = false;
                echo "Successfully disconnected. 
";
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Could Not disconnect. 
";
            return false;
        }
    }

}

    $database = new database('localhost', 'root', '');
    $database->connectdb();
    $database->select('databaseoffacebook');
    $database->disconnectdb();
```

Answer (score 0):

Object Oriented Programming works well with PDO and mysqli. Give it a try

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

class Database{

    private $link;
    //private $host,$username,$password,$database;
    //private $status;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->host         =   'localhost';
        $this->username     =   'root';
        $this->password     =   '';
        $this->database     =   'workclass';

        $this->link = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);

        $this->status = mysqli_select_db($this->link,$this->database);

        if (!$this->status) {
            return $this->status="Failed to Connected with Database";
        }else{
            return $this->status="Database is connected";
        }
    }
}

$object = new Database();

echo $object->status;

?>
```

Comment: It will be good if you explain your answer not just place bunch of code.

Comment: i am just giving my answer to above question("I have just started learning the concept of Object oriented programming and have put together a class for connecting to a database, selecting database and closing the database connection.") and we have used this code green tick mark answer and we had faced problem so we have recreate this program and give my answer. thanks

Comment: My accepted "green tick" was posted 5 years previous. The only changes you made to your answer were to add "mysqli". Please don't update an outdated question. And if you do, like @S.I. said, State your case, say you are providing updated code.