# mysqli_real_escape_string vs filter_input()? What method should I use?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I don't know when to use each one of them.

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['name']);
```

or

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filter\_input and mysqli\_real\_escape\_string for integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653099/filter-input-and-mysqli-real-escape-string-for-integers)

Answer (score 1):

`real_escape_string()` have to be used for the sql strings, i.e. parts of the query enclosed in quotes. Have to be used unconditionally, despite of whatever previous manipulations. `real_escape_string()`  Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current char set of the connection.

Where as

`filter_input` Gets a specific external variable by name and optionally filters it. `filter_input` will provide you way to validate input for specific string and characters.

1. Validate filters
2. Sanitize filters
3. Other filters
4. Filter flags

**Validate filters**

As name suggested it is use for validation for specific input like `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`.

```
$email = "abc@example"; // wrong email

if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo $email.'<br>';
    var_dump(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
}else{
    var_dump(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));   
}
```

**Sanitize filters**
it will use for validate and remove characters from string.

```
FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL   "email"         Remove all characters except letters, digits and !#$%&'*+-=?^_`{|}~@.[].
```

For more information on [filter_value](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php).

So I think that both have different roles to play.