# send ID to PHP script and return img src tag from DB filename

Tags: php, html

I am trying to do something easy I am sure but I have looked and tested and I am not doing something right.
I have a DB that stores the image file name, I need to get the file name based on the ID in the HTML , let me explain:

```
 <div class="slide">
                    <div class="image-holder">
                       <img src="img/asoft_table.jpg" alt="" /> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">

                        <p>Morbi a tellus lorem, id scelerisque ligula. Maecenas vitae turpis et.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div class="image-holder">
                        <img src="img/soft_table.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">

                        <p>Sed semper, lorem ac lobortis bibendum, magna neque varius augue, vel accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <div class="image-holder">
                        <img src="img/living_room2.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
```

in each instance of an img tag, I need to insert the filename from the DB. so, first image tag would be primary key 1, second primary key 2 and so forth.
Here is the PHP script I am using to retrieve the filename, which works, but I am unsure how to send the ID of the image to the script and then return it properly.

```
 <?php
 $hote = 'localhost';
 $base = '*****';
 $user = '*****';
 $pass = '*****';
 $cnx = mysql_connect ($hote, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error ());
 $ret = mysql_select_db ($base) or die (mysql_error ());
 $image_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ID']);
 $sql = "SELECT image FROM image_upload WHERE ID ='$image_id'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $image = mysql_result($result, 0);

 header('Content-Type: text/html');
 echo '<img src="' . $image . '"/>';
 exit;


 ?>
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks a heap

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Not related to the question, but try not to use die() in real/production applications. You can use trigger_error() instead, or another debugging mechanism.

Comment: Not sure if I get it. Does the db field contain the part URL to the image? i.e. `img/imagename.png`?

Comment: Yes, and i want to insert that filename into the img tag....but each page has about 10 tags so i need to grab them from the DB using the ID primary key...or so I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks your trying too hard to separate the PHP from HTML.

```
// File: index.php
<?php
    $hote = 'localhost';
    $base = '*****';
    $user = '*****';
    $pass = '*****';
    $cnx = mysql_connect ($hote, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error ());
    $ret = mysql_select_db ($base) or die (mysql_error ());
    $image_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ID']);
    $sql = "SELECT image FROM image_upload WHERE ID ='$image_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    //$image = mysql_result($result, 0);

    $image = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $image[] = $row["image"];
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="image-holder">
                <img src="<?php echo $image[0];?>" alt="" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <p>Morbi a tellus lorem, id scelerisque ligula. Maecenas vitae turpis et.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="image-holder">
                <img src="<?php echo $image[1];?>" alt="" />
            </div>
        <div class="info">
            <p>Sed semper, lorem ac lobortis bibendum, magna neque varius augue, vel accumsan.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="slide">
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="<?php echo $image[2];?>" alt="" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>


// This is the magic code to get all the rows out of the database :)
// $row[ field_name ];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $image[]  $row["image"];
}
```

Edit:
I'm not sure if this is what your trying to accomplish, but thought I'd share anyway.

```
$imageID1 = $_GET['id1'];
$imageID2 = $_GET['id2'];
$imageID3 = $_GET['id3'];

$sql = "SELECT image FROM image_upload ";
$sql = "WHERE ID = $imageID1 OR ID = $imageID2 OR ID = $imageID3";

//The rest of your code can remain the same.
```

Or if one id relates to 3 images.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_upload WHERE ID ='$image_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $image = array();

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $image1 =  $row["image1"];
    $image2 =  $row["image2"];
    $image3 =  $row["image3"];
```

I've you give me more info on what your trying to do, I'd be happy to give you a better example.

Comment: Note: I didn't touch any of your php logic, just moved the <?php echo $image;?> down into the HTML.

Comment: Yes, I think I was trying to hard :)ok, but how do i get a different result for each img tag...

Comment: @Jjames let me know if you want me to elaborate on my edit more.

Comment: Check out [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) There are a few different ways of accessing the data. Also building a class will solve a lot of head aches later, here's a primer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9651249/1246494](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9651249/1246494)

Comment: One more thing, should I replace the $_get[ID] with your magic code? :)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the images? Do you want to load 3 different images by form data? Then you need to do what @Tim said, script.php?id1=101&id2=102&id3=103. Otherwise you need to change your SELECT. Or will the one id, allways relate to 3 images?

Comment: no it will be 10 images, all from one table. Basically the user will upload the images, and my upload script writes the filenames  into one table, then I am calling the query to populate each image tag with those filenames. So each table is one batch of images. I was trying to keep it as simple as I could come up with. Its a simple slide show where the user uploads and then its populated out of the DB.

Comment: haha, yeah that didn't help. I'll have another look tonight. Think I need some sleep. But if each slideshow has one entry in a table, you probably want something like my 2nd example in my last edit. The user accesses the group of images with a single id.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your HTML file is actually a php file. Put the PHP code at the top of it then put your HTML below it. You can use

```
<?php echo $image; ?>
```

to put the variable in like this:

```
<div class="slide">
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <p>Sed semper, lorem ac lobortis bibendum, magna neque varius augue, vel accumsan.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's always a good idea to use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php/) for security (avoids javascript injection):

```
<img src="<?php echo htmlentities($image, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: So the PHP script that queries the DB should be in the actual HTML doc? and how do i get a result for each img tag??

Comment: There should not be a .html doc, as HTML docs are static and what you are trying to do is dynamic. You must put all your code in a .php file like @Bradley's answer. 

You are getting the image ID's from the URL using the $_GET array. If you want more images you'll need more paramaters in the URL like file.php?ID1=3242&ID2=234234&ID3=309342 then you can get each of these ID's like this $image1_id = $_GET['ID1']; $image2_id = $_GET['ID2']; etc then you do 3 different SQL queries getting the image url and echo them out in the correct places.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the $_GET array, you will want to send the ID through the URL, for instance:

```
http://www.example.com/image.php?ID=5
```

That is assuming you want to continue using $_GET for this script.

Comment: Well, I need each img tag to get a different result from the DB, maybe i am trying to do it incorrectly...any suggestions on a better way? basically the filename is in the db but i need to populate the image tags based on the ID in the DB table. so <img src= " table ID 1", and so forth

Comment: If you can output all the images from the table, then you should loop through your MySQL result with while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) and then for each row output the entire div class="slide". If you want to select only specific images, then please be more specific about which ones you are selecting and how :)

Comment: ok, that makes a lot of sense, could you possibly tell me where to put the fetch array, in place of the div tag I want to replace i assume..