# MySQL in PHP: Close connection at end of script?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to use mysql_close(connection)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651010/do-i-need-to-use-mysql-closeconnection)

Is it best to close a MySQL connection at the end of a script, or store all MySQL queries for that page in arrays at the beginning, close the connection, then output the data?

On one hand, closing it at the end seems like it would cause problems eventually if pages are constantly refreshed before the page has time to load. On the other, grabbing everything at the start would place everything into memory. If they didn't wait for the page to load completely, all of it didn't need to be loaded, so it wasted memory.

Sure, the memory gets freed. But for a site that get's a lot of hits, and a lot of constant F5's, which is the better way?

Comment: if you use any sort of caching (which you should) you don't have to worry about page refresh ... mysql connection is automatically closed when the script execution ends

Comment: please read **RELATED** section of this page >>>

Comment: more http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+close+mysql+connection

Comment: There was no reason to downgrade this question. I looked over the other ones, and this question was different from them. They wanted to know if they had to close the connection or not. I wanted to know if it was best to close it before the script ends, then process the data that was pulled.

Comment: This is not the same question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you don't have to close connections, they are handled internally.

Also doing all your queries, and then closing the connection could cause problems when you try and fetch result sets.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using persistent connections (mysql_pconnect) then the connection gets closed as the script finishes anyway. So the only reason to add mysql_close() would be to make you code cleaner / easier to read.

With persistent connections, you would leave them open as they are left open and picked up by another process.

Mysql is very efficient at opening and closing connections.